# Where do we use arithmetic multipliers in 5G technology?

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications, cellular

I have recently learned about arithmetic multiplication and the various types of multipliers used in digital circuit design. Now, having an interest in cellular technology, I am curious about the applications of these multipliers in 5G circuits. For example, I have done some research and found that they can be used in the minimum-mean-squared-error minimization in MIMO receivers. Where else would I find arithmetic multiplication being performed in cellular technology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply-accumulate is a basic operation of most signal processing algorithms. It's found pretty much any place signal processing is performed - filtering, correlation, normalization, Discrete Fourier Transform, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some older (GSM) receivers would perform a gradual phase-de_rotation along the 500 bit packet.

This would use I+Q products in the Intermediate Frequency channels, once digitized.

This would have eased the system-level spec on close-in phase noise.